# Android Broadcast Intent not working between 2 separate applications

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am trying to shutdown an activity from another application, hence another activity. I am doing this using the BroadcastReceiver class and Intent.

Here's what I do:

In the first Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.update_btn).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("<package name here>");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
            intent.setAction("finish_activity");
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

I send a broadcast with a specific action.

In the other app's activity I am doing the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    [...]
    BroadcastReceiver broadcast_reciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
            System.out.println("Received broadcast!!");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "received broadcast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals("finish_activity")) {
                postEvent(new ShutdownEvent());
                finish();
                // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT.
            }
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(broadcast_reciever, new IntentFilter("finish_activity"));
}
```

Mainly I create the Receiver and I register it. However this doesn't seem to be working, it seems that my code does not execute until here.

Any suggestions highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In order to expose your BroadcastReceiver to the other apps, you should declare it in your manifest, and mark it as `exported`. This way the system knows how to trigger it.

A good article on how to use BroadcastReceivers
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html#ownreceiver_create